# Mongoexport - modify large array fields to their counts

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a large collection that I'd like to export to CSV, but I'd like to do some trimming to some of the fields. (e.g. I just need to know the number of elements in some, and just to know if others exist or not in the doc)

I would like to do the equivalent to a `map` function on the fields, so that fields that contain a list will be exported to the list size, and some fields that sometimes exist and sometimes do not, I would like to have them exported as boolean flags.

e.g. if my rows looks like this

```
{_id:"id1", listField:[1,2,3], optionalField: "...", ... }
{_id:"id2", listField:[1,2,3,4], ... }
```

I'd like to run a mongoexport to CSV that will result in this

```
 _id, listField.length, optinalField.exists 
"id1", 3,             , true
"id2", 4,             , false
```

Is that possible using mongoexport? (assume MongoDB version 3.0) 
If not, is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

The [`mongoexport`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) utility itself is pretty spartan and just a basic tool bundled in the suite. You can add "query" filters, but pretty much just like [`.find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) queries in general, the intention is to return documents "as is" rather than "manipulate" the content.

Just as with other query operations, the [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method is something useful for document manipulation. So in order to "manipulate" the output to something different from the original document source, you would do:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "listField": { "$size": "$listField" },
        "optionalField": { 
            "$cond": [
                { "$ifNull": [ "$optionalField", false ] },
                true, 
                false
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

The [**`$size`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator returns the "size" of the array, and the [**`$ifNull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) tests for the presence, either returning the field value or the alternate. Pass that result into [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to get a `true/false` return rather than the field value. "_id" is always implicit, unless you specifically ask to omit it.

That would give you the "reduced" output, but in order to go to CSV then you would have to code that export yourself, as `mongoexport` does not run aggregation pipeline queries.

But the code to do so should be quite trivial ( pick a library for your language ), and the aggregation statement is also trivial as you can see here.

For the *"really basic"* approach, then just send a script to the `mongo` shell, as a very rudimentary form of programming:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "listField": { "$size": "$listField" },
        "optionalField": { 
            "$cond": [
                { "$ifNull": [ "$optionalField", false ] },
                true, 
                false
            ]
        }
    }}
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    print(Object.keys(doc).map(function(key) {
      return doc[key]
    }).join(","));
});
```

Which would output:

```js
id1,3,true
id2,4,false
```